# Mensa IQ test question - shapes in a 4x3 grid

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, visual

> Select the figure that is missing from the collection below:
>
> [image]
>
> a.[image]
>
> b.[image]
>
> c.[image]
>
> d.[image]

Comment: There's no figure missing. The question mark belongs there. GG, mensa.

Comment: I like how your answer makes more sense than the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Answer:

> A

### Explanation:

> All the possible answers except for A are in the collection. (Some of them just rotated or slightly different). But A is not, there is no triangle with **5** lines in the collection, just one with 4 lines. The most conspicuous thing is that nothing is being "added" to the other three possibilites. (This should make it clear that A is the right answer)

Comment: I do not doubt yours could very well be the correct answer, but couldn't the third and seventh be considered the same (sort of)

Comment: @Goinghamateur You're right! (I overlooked that) Maybe Mensa just considers this a more "drastic" change than B, C and D... I know that seems very far-fetched, but I honestly can't think of another "rule", nor another correct answer to this puzzle.

Answer (score 17):

Since the answer already has been accepted I would add this as a comment, but I do not have sufficient points to do so. I agree that the answer should be...

> A

but due to the reason that...

> ... in the two upper rows, each row contains two figures which encloses an area, and two that does not. Therefore, the figure replacing the question mark should enclose an area, which leaves only figure A.

Comment: I think this is the better answer as the reasoning makes much more sense. My answer is just like "_Every figure must be different_", yours actually explains a "rule" in the collection, which I think every IQ question has.

Comment: IMO, that a better reason.

Answer (score -2):

Each symbol is unique , hence ( since the Mensa authors want this as logic not reasoning )
There's no level of reasonably thinking . So it is a " hence " answer.  Answer c) since it is only symbol unique as the others would be repeats and there are no repeats in the symbol grid .

Comment: How is C more "unique" than B or D? They all exist in the table, flipped or rotated, except for A.

Comment: I can't understand this - are you using some special mensa-specific jargon? What does "logic not reasoning" mean and what us a "hence answer"? Also, C is just the top left symbol upside down which is not unique at all, while A (5 sticks) actually is unique

Comment: My point is Mensa is wrong . The figure in c) is not necessarily turned upside down.  He the other figures b) and d) are clearly modified versions of their counterparts above . So logically the answer could be both a) and C)